# Using AppCompat with Holo theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've updated my support library to 21.0.3 using Android SDK Manager. Now when I use Theme.AppCompat.Light a Material Theme is applied.

Is there a way for me to use this support library to apply a Holo theme, or do I need to use an old support library? If I need to use an old library, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using the Material theme provided by the new Support Library. First time I've downloaded it accidentally, but now I've migrated by my choice.
I don't know if you will be able to use anymore the Holo Theme, but you can download the last Android Support Revision 20 by clicking the link below.

[Android Support revision 20](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r20.zip)

Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score -2):

You should get somewhere old Support Library - revision 20 is suitable - and add this version to your projects. This autumn after revision-21 was released, Google "offers" old revision in bundles.

I compiled my app with rev20 - and didn't find any problems.

Support lib rev20 is about 10 Mb; I can email it to you if you'll fail to find it in the Internet.